# node internal error MODULE_NOT_FOUND by global install but not by local install

Tags: node.js, npm-install, suppress-warnings

My goal is to get a cli I can execute every where.
Seem the better way is global install.
But when I try, it raise an error like if a required module was missing.
Can't resolve this even after an `npm install -g <missing_module>`

I am using nvm with several node version so I think it can be a root cause.
But when I check in node_modules of the current node version used, I find missing module.

I do not understand.

I put the steps to reproduce here with a little exemple test2 project.
Note than my issue come from another big project where I encounter issue on dotenv-safe/config too.

If I resolve for this given exemple I think I will be able to resolve for the others missing modules.

```
$ mkdir -p test2
$ cd test2
$ npm init -y
$ echo '[{"key": "1"}]' > jsonFile.json
$ touch index.js
$ chmod +x index.js
```

Add this in package.json :

```json
  "type": "module",
  "bin": {
    "test2-cli": "./index.js"
  },
```

```
$ cat index.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import jsonContent from './jsonFile.json' assert { type: "json"}
console.log(jsonContent)
```

```
$ ./index.js 
[ { key: '1' } ]
(node:5362) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Following [João Pimentel advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766698/6862843), I add `--experimental-modules` tag.
And I do not want the warning, so I add `--require=suppress-experimental-warnings` option.

So I replace in `index.js`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

by

```js
#!/usr/bin/env -S node --experimental-modules --require=suppress-experimental-warnings
```

```
$ ./index.js 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'suppress-experimental-warnings'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1395:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:621:5)
    at setupUserModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:125:3)
    at prepareExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:116:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:36:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

```
$ npm install suppress-experimental-warnings

added 1 package in 536ms

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

```
$ ./index.js 
[ { key: '1' } ]
```

Ok, now I want to access to this cli every where in my terminal.

```
$ npm install -g .

added 2 packages in 1s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

```
$ cd ../
$ test2-cli
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'suppress-experimental-warnings'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1395:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:621:5)
    at setupUserModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:125:3)
    at prepareExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:116:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:36:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

```
$ npm install -g suppress-experimental-warnings

added 1 package in 534ms

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

```
$ test2-cli
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'suppress-experimental-warnings'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1395:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:621:5)
    at setupUserModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:125:3)
    at prepareExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:116:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:36:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

```
$ nvm ls
        v6.14.4
       v14.15.5
       v16.10.0
       v16.17.0
->     v18.13.0
        v19.5.0
default -> lts/* (-> v18.13.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v19.5.0) (default)
stable -> 19.5 (-> v19.5.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.13.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.2 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.19.0 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.13.0
```

```
$ npm prefix -g
/home/bjam/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0
```

```
$ ls -la /home/bjam/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/ | grep suppress-
drwxr-xr-x  3 bjam bjam 4096 Mar 17 11:00 suppress-experimental-warnings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve it by replacing experimental json import by `readFileSync` combined to `URL` and `import.meta.url` to resolve relative path from the project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S node 

import { readFileSync } from 'fs'

const filePath = new URL('jsonFile.json', import.meta.url)
const jsonContent = JSON.parse(readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'))
console.log(jsonContent)
```

With `readFileSync`, have to think than a relative path is relative to the current working directory (where the script is called) and not relative to the project (where the `package.json` is stored).

Relative path to the current working directory :

```js
readFileSync('jsonFile.json', 'utf-8')
```

Relative path to the current file :

```js
new URL('jsonFile.json', import.meta.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, instead of going down the path of using *suppress-experimental-warnings*, you can specify the `--no-warnings` flag to suppress this:

```
(node:5362) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Do so by modifying the first line of your index.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S node --experimental-modules --no-warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `require` instead, since `import` is not fully supported, unless you use the `--experimental-modules` tag, ex: `node --experimental-modules index.js`

With `require`:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs')
const jsonContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./jsonFile.json'))
console.log(jsonContent)
```

Comment: You think that this option is not required for local install but required in global install ? I will try, thank you.

Comment: When I add this tag after the shebang, (see edited question) and resinstall globally, the error still occured

Comment: When I replace experimental json import by this : 
`import { readFileSync } from 'fs'; const jsonContent = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./jsonFile.json')); ` 
And delete tags and options `--experimental-modules --require=suppress-experimental-warnings`, 
I get the following error only by using global install :
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './jsonFile.json' `

Comment: I discover than opening a file with relative path by readFileSync means that this is not relative to the current project (where the package.json is stored) but about the current working dir (where the script is called). So, installed localy or globaly, I get the same error `ENOENT: no such file or directory`  when I call the script from the parent directory of the project : localy by `./test2/index` and globally by `user@pc:~/parentDirOfTest2$ test2-cli`.

Comment: I can't use require because I am in an ESM module (`index.js` has a `.js` file extension and `package.json` contains `"type": "module"`).

Comment: @BJam use `require('path').join(__dirname, './jsonFile.json')`